# Missing file entries when multiple threads-generated processes copy files to same directory C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, cmd, multiprocessing, xcopy

I am trying to copy large number of files from various directories on different hosts to a single directory. Since it turned out to be quite time consuming, and I have to run this program multiple times, I changed the code to leverage the help of multi-thread, with each thread doing XCOPY through a process.

However, I found out that when I am doing multi-thread copying, some files (less than 100, varies each time) are not getting copied. I have not figured whether it's because of multiple processes intervening each other when XCOPYing to the same directory, or it's more of a XCOPY issue (not sure how well it supports multi-process calling on same destination).

```
List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>;

foreach(FileEntry fileEntry in fileEntries)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
        //full path of file, like \\host\directory\directoryB\fileA.txt
        string filePath = fileEntry._filePath;

        //name of file, like fileA.txt
        string file = fileEntry._file;

        //dumpDirectory is where I want to copy all the files to
        string destPath = Path.Combine(dumpDirectory, file);

        //each file here is either a directory or a real file, bad naming convention I know...(open to suggestions if any)
        string fileType = File.Exists(filePath) ? "f" : "d";

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/C echo {0} | XCOPY /E /C /H /R /K /O /Y {1} {2}", fileType, filePath, destPath);

            Console.WriteLine("copying {2} [{0}] to destination [{1}]", filePath, destPath, string.Compare(fileType, "f") == 0 ? "file" : "directory");
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            if (process.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("encountered problems when copying file [{0}]", filePath);
            }
        }
    });

    thread.Start();
    threadList.Add(thread);
}

foreach(Thread thread in threadList)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

---------------------------Bug Fix As Following -------------------------------

So as suggested by replies below (thanks guys for the quick replies, saved my weekend ^_^), I redirected the process output and found out that the issue is "Sharing violation \n Unable to create directory ". xcopy is having issues when copying multiple files into the same directory (various xcopy processes seem to create a directory at the same time when they all detect that the directory does not exist on the system).

Changing the manual thread management to Parallel.Foreach solved the problem and made the code look nicer (though I have not figured out why it is not creating the same problem)

Or, a dirtier fix is to wrap up the process.Start() with a EventWaitHandle. I used different EventWaitHandle instances based on the destination directory rather than using one handle because the other way will defeat the purpose of using multi-process

```
//name the wait handle based on destination value
EventWaitHandle destWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, string.Format("waitHandle{0}", destPath.GetHashCode()));

//only trigger the wait handle lock if the file being copied from (and to) is a directory. Based on the error log info XCopy seemed to never have issues with copying individual files
//and the program worked fine if I only put the lock at directory level
if (string.Compare(fileType, "d") == 0)
{
    destWaitHandle.WaitOne();
}

process.Start();

//this line was added to write error messages into respective files during the process' execution
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();

if (string.Compare(fileType, "d") == 0)
{
    destWaitHandle.Set();
}
```

Comment: Probably you could show the StandardOutput from Process.Start... Something is happening there

Comment: I don't know how to directly reply to the above comment but I just want to thank you [x...] for the help. As suggested, I redirected/ dumped the entire output and found out where the issue was.

Comment: There is very little point to using multi-threading to copy files. Threads are beneficial if you have CPU-bound operations. With IO the CPU is virtually idle. In fact, multi-threading IO can **slow down** the copying because you introduce hard drive contention and it can **cause errors** in the copying process.

Comment: @Enigmativity contention and errors indeed happened as far as I see, and I had to implement the lock or parallel.foreach() to get it to work. The speed boost is very obvious, however (by a factor of 2~4 I didn't count). The source files are located on remote hosts and the destination is a directory on the server. Given your explanation about IO bound tasks, my guess is that the original copying files task was more bounded by network bandwidths of those remote hosts. It probably never reached the hardware limitation of the destination server until the job got paralleled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to switch to the Task-oriented code, as the creation on threads in such number could lead to downgrade the performance because of the context switches.

You easily can do this with Parallel extensions, like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileEntries, fileEntry => { // YOUR code here };
```

Second, you can investigate the error occured in the `XCOPY` process by examing the `StandardError` property of the `Process` object, as @x... suggested, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5005952/213550) (you also have to redirect it for ability to read it):

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
// ...
if (process.ExitCode != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("encountered problems when copying file [{0}]", filePath);
    Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dumped the messages into a file and found out where the issue was. In the error dump file it says "Sharing Violation \n Unable to create directory <destination directory>". I wrapped the process.Start() with a waitHandle (essentially a inter-process level lock) based on the hash value of destination directory, and the files are all copied correctly.  The Parallel.Foreach is definitely a more preferred method though. I tried it first without using the waitHandle and the program worked fine (though I did not find out why it did not end up into the same trouble).

Comment: @T.L. I think that the issue was solved by the `Parallel` approach as it starts only a given number of threads in a moment so the race won't happen.