# Executing Powershell Script fails in c#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell

My powershell script fails to run with the following error:

[image: Code]
On this line: -

"Import-AzureRmContext -Path C:\profile.json;"

If I right click the file and "Run with powershell" then the script runs fine.

If I run using PowerShellInstance, get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Possibly a working directory or something not being set? whats "scriptfile" variable hold?

Comment: Just the name and path of the file i.e. "C:\PowerShellScript.ps1" which must be OK because it is reading the first line of the script to give that error?

Comment: what happens if you try process.start(scriptFile) ? And capture the error and output from it?

There's an example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005874/how-to-get-the-error-message-with-c-sharp

Comment: added another image trying to use PowerShellInstance to run the file. Same error but with additional 2nd error. Using process.start just says its not a valid executable.

Comment: Is the file association for PS1 files set correctly? right click run with powershell forces it to open with powershell but if you double click the file what does it open with?


I've just tried myself and mines set to notepad, so when I do process.start it opens with Notepad. If yours is set to something else it may cause the "invalid executable" error. Running out of ideas....

Comment: My file opens in notepad too. That sent me down another route and I've got it working now. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code from another StackOverflow Post. Which you can use to execute powershell scripts using command prompt. This worked for me using the below function and call:

```
ExecuteCommand("powershell -command \" & C:\\PowershellFileName.ps1\"");

public void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
{
    ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
    Process Process;

    ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);
    ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
}
```